# How to draw polyline similar to google map app in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

The polyline which we will draw on the map is not similar to the polyline of google's map application.It is giving a nice 3d feel,can we draw the polyline similar to that polyline?.Is it possible to draw using 9-patch images?.Anyone please help?.

Comment: no it is not possible. Indeed GoogleMaps is not using play services api like us, but they have a lot of more methods to use.

Answer (score 0):

Hello  this would help you, it helped me.

Firstly make the google api server key from Google developer account then add a dependency for google direction.

```
compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
```

then it check that feasible and shortest route between LatLongs.

use this code to check route is available or not.

```
GoogleDirection.withServerKey(getResources().getString(R.string.SERVER_KEY))
                    .from(SourceLatlng)
                    .to(DestinationLatlng)
                    .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String message) {
                            if (direction.isOK()) {
                                DrawRoute(direction, message,SourceLatlng,DestinationLatlng);
                            } else {
                                //selectedRawLine = ERROR;
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                            t.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
```

Using this we can find that route is feasible or not

```
private void DrawRoute(Direction direction, String message,LatLng sourceLatlng,LatLng DestinationLng) {

        for (Route route : direction.getRouteList()) {
            PolylineOptions polyoptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polyoptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
            polyoptions.width(5);
            polyoptions.addAll(route.getOverviewPolyline().getPointList());
            poly = googleMap.addPolyline(polyoptions);
            poly.setClickable(true);

        }
        LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        if(sourceLatlng!=null)
        latLngBuilder.include(sourceLatlng);
        if(DestinationLng!=null)
        latLngBuilder.include(DestinationLng);

        try {
            LatLngBounds bounds = latLngBuilder.build();
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                    UiHelper.dpToPixel(getActivity(), 135));
            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Using this code we make polyline between two latLongs ...

Comment: I tried poly line,but google map's(System App) poly line is different from this polyline

Comment: you can change the color of poly line same as map polyline and change the width of polyline from using this.

Comment: polyoptions.width(5);

Comment: make it 5 to 10.